# How can I extract files in the directory where they're located with the find command?

Tags: bash, find, tar

I have tried to extract multiple files from the directory where they're located with:

```
for i in $(find . -name '*.tgz'); do  # search the tgz files and extract them
    tar -xvzf $i
done
```

I expected that the command would extract these files within the directory they were found in, however they are extracted outside their directory. How can I make sure that the .tgz files are extracted in the directory where they are located?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should avoid constructions like `for i in $(find . -name '*.tgz'); do ...` - see for example [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice) - instead, use `-exec` or `-execdir` to run the command directly on found files whenever possible.

For your application, `-execdir` will do exactly what you want i.e. execute `tar` relative to each `.tgz` file's containing directory:

```
find . -name '*.tgz' -execdir tar -xvf {} \;
```

See also [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find).

Answer (score 4):

You need to look at the `tar` man page:  `man tar`

Found in `man tar`

```
   -C, --directory=DIR
          Change to DIR before performing any operations.  This option  is
          order-sensitive, i.e. it affects all options that follow.
```

And using a command that will give you the directory name of a path is `dirname`.  Then you could add on to your command `-C $(dirname $i)` to extract to the directory that the tar file was found in.  So, you would just change your command to:

```
for i in $(find . -name '*.tgz'); do
    tar -xvzf $i -C $(dirname $i)
done
```

Comment: Good job, that indeed works! @Cook4733 I hope you can mark his answer as the accepted answer.